# Firebase - Filter by list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this:

```
"solCompras" : {
    "-KdTAI4IUPrAXnz4UKwD" : {
      "words" : {
        "-KdTAI4HdSdjANZYPrUs" : "one",
        "-KdTAI4IUPrAXnz4UKwB" : "two",
        "-KdTAI4IUPrAXnz4UKwC" : "three"
      },
      "post" : "yyyy",
      "user" : "demo"
    },
    "-KdTBH9LRyD0tZwa7tBj" : {
      "words" : {
        "-KdTBH9LRyD0tZwa7tBf" : "four",
        "-KdTBH9LRyD0tZwa7tBg" : "five"
      },
      "post" : "xxxx",
      "user" : "demo"
    }
 }
```

How can I filter `solcompras` which have at least one word equal to `one`? Thanks.

Comment: This is a classic "give me all items in a category" problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: excelent "frank-van-puffelen" thank you